# EntityFramework Core 2.1: Access and change options after configuring DbContext?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-core-2.1

In EntityFramework Core you can add different options by using the `DbContextOptionsBuilder`.

Is it possible to access the options which are set for a `DbContext` later?

In my case I would like to know if the Lazy Loading with Proxies is activated (the functionality is added by using the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies` package).

Additionally is it possible after the creation and configuration of the `DbContext` to change these configured options?

Comment: Other option means connection details? You can use `DbConnection con = _context.Database.GetDbConnection();` to obtain it.

Comment: More like if an option (in my case the proxy creation) is activated or not. For example you can ask via DbContext.ChangeTracker if AutoDetectChanges or LazyLoading is enabled (and set it if you need to).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more digging into the current code of EFCore 2.1 I found something.

If you keep a reference to the `DbContextOptionsBuilder` in your `DbContext` you can access extensions and the related values. Example:

```
context.OptionsBuilder.Options.FindExtension<ProxiesOptionsExtension>()?.UseLazyLoadingProxies;
```

**BUT** it is **NOT RECOMMENDED** by the EFCore team. The comment for using `ProxiesOptionsExtension` reads:

> This API supports the Entity Framework Core infrastructure and is not
>   intended to be used directly from your code. This API may change or be
>   removed in future releases.

Be aware of that.

I implemented it, but it will take a few days before I can try it out and say for sure that it works like I intended it to work. (I have to add a lot of additional stuff around it for my scenario.)

I will keep you posted.